# I have ascii characters errors django-tagging in admin panel

Tags: django, tags, django-tagging

I'm using django-tagging for tags. But I have a problem. Tags have a ascii character. Example: ı

Problem =>

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/tagging/taggeditem/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://blog.com/admin/tagging/taggeditem/
```

Comment: Did you mean "Tags have an NON-ASCII character"?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, Tags have an NON-ASCII charackter. Example = "hakkında"